# Error: File not found while importing file from framework

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, mapkit, cartodb

I am following this [Demo Tutorial URL](http://mousebird.github.io/WhirlyGlobe/tutorial/ios/your_first_map.html) to add layer on map which is provided by `cartoDb`. I have `WhirlyGlobe_Maply_Distribution_2_4` binary files and its framework and importing its component file. But its showing me that file not found.

Here is what i write to import it:

```
#import <MaplyComponent.h>
```

Please help.  i want to use it in my app. Thank you

Comment: shoudln't it be like this: #import <MaplyComponent/MaplyComponent.h> or just #import "MaplyComponent.h" if its in your .m file

Comment: @Konsy No i tried it.

Comment: have you tried reimporting the files

Comment: Check "Link Binary With Libraries". If it's not there, include it using "+" button.

Comment: @Konsy Yes i tried a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Step 1** - Go to Project > General > Linked Framework And Libraries

**Step 2** - Select MaplyComponent Framework And Remove it.

**Step 3** - Just Above There is Embeded Binaries Just Click "+" there and Add  MaplyComponent Framework.

**Step 4** - As you add it you will see it in Both Boxes.

And you can import the files from Framework now.